# jquery animate run on click again not running

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this codes below that just make elements move left and right by increasing and decreasing there right and left values

```
$('#signup').click(function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('#anim1 .bg-box .overlay-box #signin-text,#anim2 #signin-form').hide();
        $('#signup-text,#anim2 #signup-form').fadeIn();
      },300)
      $('#anim1').animate({ 'right' : '0px' },500);
      $('#anim2').animate({ 'right' : 'initial','left' : '0px' },500);
  });

  $('#signin').click(function(){
      $('#anim1').animate({ 'left' : '0px','right' : 'initial' },500);
      $('#anim2').animate({ 'right' : '0px','left' : 'initial' },500);
  });
```

at first, it will animate but when i trigger below event

```
$('#signin').click(function(){

      $('#anim1').animate({ 'left' : '0px','right' : 'initial' },500);
      $('#anim2').animate({ 'right' : '0px','left' : 'initial' },500);
  });
```

this line animate

```
 $('#anim1').animate({ 'left' : '0px','right' : 'initial' },500);
```

but this line is not

```
$('#anim2').animate({ 'right' : '0px','left' : 'initial' },500);
```

any ideas, help please? you can check the actual demo [here](https://www.connectnigeria.com/anim-sample/index.html)

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki No, just click the "sign up" and the "sign in" buttons.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki no, click on signup, it will animate, then it will show the sign in button, click it, and you'll see what i mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give the width percentage  you have provided for elements for left, right . Below is the working snippet you can replace.

```
  $('#signup').click(function(){
          setTimeout(function(){
            $('#anim1 .bg-box .overlay-box #signin-text,#anim2 #signin-form').hide();
            $('#signup-text,#anim2 #signup-form').fadeIn();
          },300)
          $('#anim1').animate({ 'right' : '0px','left':'56%' },500);
          $('#anim2').animate({ 'right' : '44%','left' : '0px' },500);
      });

      $('#signin').click(function(){
          setTimeout(function(){
            $('#anim1 .bg-box .overlay-box #signup-text,#anim2 #signup-form').hide();
            $('#signin-text,#anim2 #signin-form').fadeIn();
          },300);
          $('#anim1').animate({ 'left' : '0px','right' : '56%' },500);
          $('#anim2').animate({ 'right' : '0px','left' : '44%' },500);
      });
```